# How to use boost::spirit to modify a string like regex does?

Tags: boost, boost-spirit

I'm writing a little Domain Specific Language for my program, using [JUCE::JavascriptEngine](https://docs.juce.com/master/classJavascriptEngine.html) as the scripting engine. This takes a string as input and then parses it, but I need to do some pre-processing on the string to adapt it from my DSL to JavaScript. The pre-processing mainly consists of wrapping some terms inside functions, and placing object names in front of functions. So, for instance, I want to do something like this:

take some special string input `"~/1/2"`...

wrap it inside a function: `"find("~/1/2")"`...

and then attach an object to it: `"someObject.find("~/1/2")"` (the object name has to be a variable).

I've been using regex for this (now I have two problems...). The regexes are getting complicated and unreadable, and it's missing a lot of special cases. Since what I'm doing is grammatical, I thought I'd upgrade from regex to a proper parser (now I have three problems...). After quite a lot of research, I chose Boost.Spirit. I've been going through the documentation, but it's not taking me in the right direction. Can someone suggest how I might use this library to manipulate strings in the way I am looking for? Given that I am only trying to manipulate a string and am not interested in storing the parsed data, do I need to use `karma` for the output, or can I output the string with `qi` or `x3`, during the parsing process?

If I'm headed down the wrong path here, please feel free to re-direct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems too broad to answer.

What you're doing is *parsing* input, and transforming it to something else. What you're not doing is find/replace (otherwise you'd be fine using regular expressions).

Of course you can do what regular expressions do, but I'm not sure it buys you anything:

```
template <typename It, typename Out>
Out preprocess(It f, It l, Out out) {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    using boost::spirit::repository::qi::seek;

    auto passthrough = [&out](boost::iterator_range<It> ignored, auto&&...) {
        for (auto ch : ignored) *out++ = ch;
    };
    auto transform = [&out](std::string const& literal, auto&&...) {
        for (auto ch : "someObject.find(\"~"s) *out++ = ch;
        for (auto ch : literal) *out++ = ch;
        for (auto ch : "\")"s) *out++ = ch;
    };

    auto pattern = qi::copy("\"~" >> (*~qi::char_('"')) >> '"');
    qi::rule<It> ignore = qi::raw[+(!pattern >> qi::char_)] [passthrough];
    qi::parse(f, l, -qi::as_string[pattern][transform] % ignore);
    return out;
}
```

The nice thing about this way of writing it, is that it will work with any source iterator:

```
for (std::string const input : {
    R"(function foo(a, b) { var path = "~/1/2"; })",
})
{
    std::cout << "Input: " << input << "\n";

    std::string result;
    preprocess(begin(input), end(input), back_inserter(result));

    std::cout << "Result: " << result << "\n";
}

std::cout << "\n -- Or directly transformed stdin to stdout:\n";
preprocess(
    boost::spirit::istream_iterator(std::cin >> std::noskipws), {},
    std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cout));
```

See it [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9766f21427116496), printing the output:

```
Input: function foo(a, b) { var path = "~/1/2"; }
Result: function foo(a, b) { var path = someObject.find("~/1/2"); }

 -- Or directly transformed stdin to stdout:
function bar(c, d) { var path = someObject.find("~/1/42"); }
```

But this is very limited since it will not even do the right thing if such things are parts of comments or [multiline strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6247331/85371) etc.

So instead you probably want a dedicated library that **knows how to parse javascript** and use it to do your transformation, such as (one of the first hits when googling [*`tooling library preprocess javascript transform`*](https://www.google.com/search?q=tooling+library+preprocess+javascript+transform&ie=UTF-8)): https://clojurescript.org/reference/javascript-library-preprocessing